# How do you climb out of a river in Adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I deliberately entered a river in order to cross it. I used <kbd>Alt+direction</kbd> and my adventurer began swimming around the river. But now I can't climb out, on neither of the two shores.

Is there a different key combination to climb out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you at least a novince swimmer?  Because if you're not

> Dabbling or untrained swimmers will start drowning immediately upon contact with water, and **require a ramp or stairway to get out**. If neither are accessible, they're *done for*.
> <sub>(Emphasis Mine)</sub>

If you are, you should  be able to alt-move above.

> To get out, alt-move carefully against a shoreline and select the option to move above.

**From:** [Dwarf Fortress Wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org): [DF2010:Swimmer](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Swimming)

Comment: Yes, I am a novice swimmer. Whenever I tried to alt-move against the shore, nothing happened. If I alt-moved somewhere into the river it worked, but it didn't work if I moved into the shore. Luckily I got out because the river turned into a brook farther up. Maybe it was a bug.

Comment: @Martinho Bugs happen.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be that the river is in a 1 block high canyon, so you swim to the side but it's a (small) cliff rather than a shore. If that's the case then I think you're SOL.